# How to add a service reference in VB.NET through a code?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services

I want to make a program that will ask the user to enter the service reference URL in the text box then click a button to add the service reference.

Can someone give me a sample code how to add and remove a service reference?

Comment: What do you mean, "Add the web service"? Also, what version of .NET?

Comment: Sorry! I mean add service reference. The part where you need to right click your solution then click "add service reference". I wanted to do it through a code.

Comment: But "Add Service Reference" adds it to your project. What do you want to add, and what do you want to add it _to_? What do you intend to do with it once it's added?

Comment: I'm developing something for JIRA. I need to search for the service in this url "http://ip:port/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl". But if JIRA is located in a different server you need to change the IP and the PORT, that is why I wanted to know how to add it through a code so I could just ask the user for the ip and port.

Comment: You don't need to change the code!

Comment: Yes I don't need to change the code but I need to change the service reference.

Comment: No, you don't need to change the service reference. You need to change the URL. See my answer.

Comment: If WCF Service changes (Contracts changes) it is required "Update Reference". If none changes in WCF Service contracts, like @JohnSaunders say, only change URL.

Answer (score 1):

When you use "Add Service Reference" to create a proxy class, it creates a class, and also updates your config file. If Jira moves to a different server, you need only change the URL in your config file.