# How to create a WCF client, that will update service reference programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

I don't exactly know, how to ask this question. 
I have 3 computers in my local network. On first computer I have installed windows service which hosts WCF Services (binding netTcp). So my address is "net.tcp://localhost:8523/Sms" for example.

Now, I would like to use that service from other two computers. I don't know If I have access to that WCF service - I don't how to check it.

And also I don't know, How to create a WCF client, that will update service reference programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a service reference in VB.NET through a code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707996/how-to-add-a-service-reference-in-vb-net-through-a-code)

Comment: You don't have to touch the code. Touch the config file. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate. I want to create a WCF client - simple windows program, that will update service reference after every open. (By update I mean, that action in visual studio - right click on Service and click "Update Service Reference"). I want to do that in case my WCF service will change. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh. Do you realize that "Update Service Reference" creates and/or changes code, and that the code needs to be compiled? So, no, not really. It doesn't actually make sense. What would your client do if an operation changed its return type? What if an operation was removed.

Comment: @Marshall Service**Contract**, Operation**Contract** etc. It is a contract between server and client. You can't change it whenever you want

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I understand.. but could you tell me how to check if another computer in my local network has access to WCF service (host by netTcp)?